# Memory Usage Increase but I top command could not show the process that takes memory

Tags: server, memory-usage

I have a system that run on ubuntu server 14.04. Gradually the memory becomes small. I navigate each process using top command all processes are not taking that much memory since they took when the system start. I couldn't find the problem that takes my RAM usage. I have 16GB memory and after some times the memory becomes almost 175254 KB and all my application took almost 5GB total. so where is the other memory and how couldn't this thing happen ? Is there another method to clean the memory area that is used by unidentified process. If you have an idea, please share me.

Comment: is it being used by HHD drive cache?

Comment: http://linuxatemyram.com